# Type instability in Julia Generator

Tags: julia

While trying to reduce the number of allocations generated by a function computing a likelihood by e.g. using Generator expressions, I came across the following behavior which I do not quite understand. Take the following two functions:

```
function testMax!(x,X,β)
    xmax = 0.0
    @inbounds for i ∈ eachindex(x)
        x[i] = X[i,2] * β[1] + X[i,2] * β[2]
        if x[i] > xmax 
            xmax = x[i]
        end 
    end 
    y = 0.0 
    for i ∈ eachindex(x)
        y += exp(x[i]-xmax)
    end
    return xmax, y
end

function testMaxWeird!(x,X,β)
    xmax = 0.0
    @inbounds for i ∈ eachindex(x)
        x[i] = X[i,2] * β[1] + X[i,2] * β[2]
        if x[i] > xmax 
            xmax = x[i]
        end 
    end 
    y = sum(exp(x[j]-xmax) for j ∈ eachindex(x))
    return xmax, y
end
```

Both generate the same output

```
using Random
Random.seed!(1234)
H = 10000;
X = rand(H,2);
β = rand(2);

x = zeros(H);
testMax!(x,X,β)
x = zeros(H);
testMaxWeird!(x,X,β)
```

returns (1.0772897308017204, 6101.682959406999). However, the first one is type stable, while the second one is not (and therefore much slower).

```
@code_warntype testMax!(x,X,β)
@code_warntype testMaxWeird!(x,X,β)
```

In particular, the problem lies with the type of `y` and `xmax`, the difference in the outputs being in the `@code_warntype` lines

```
y::Float64
xmax::Float64
```

versus

```
 y::Any
 xmax@_9::Core.Box
```

I am just confused as of why exactly this occurs, and whether it is due to bad practice on how I am defining `xmax` multiple times within the function, or to the way I am using the Generator expression?

#### Edit/Follow-up

The references and solutions provided are very helpful. I am still somewhat confused as to when exactly this can be expected to happen -- is it due to the way that `xmax` is updated within the for-loop, is its scope different from any other local variable defined within the function? Why does e.g. the (less efficient) way of computing the max not lead to the same closure issue?

```
function testMax2!(x,X,β)
    @inbounds for i ∈ eachindex(x)
        x[i] = X[i,2] * β[1] + X[i,2] * β[2]
    end 
    xmax = maximum(x)
    y = sum(exp(x[j]-xmax) for j ∈ eachindex(x))            
    return xmax, y
end
```

**Edit 2**: Nevermind, I think the Performance Tips explain this: "The parser, when translating it into lower-level instructions, substantially reorganizes the above code by extracting the inner function to a separate code block." I assume that this means that it comes from the variable being assigned multiple times such that the "reordering" of the code might lead to confusion.

Comment: Seems to be some kind of closure-boxing issue that  comprehensions also used to have a long time ago. Changing the `y = ...` line to `y = let xmax = xmax 
             sum(exp(x[j]-xmax) for j ∈ eachindex(x))
           end
` gets rid of the boxing, fyi. (I don't know the issue deeply enough to write out a proper answer though.)

Comment: For more info refer to the "Performance of captured variable" section here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-captured

Comment: The reference by @BallpointBen has a very nice explanation (and Sundar's solution solves the issue and runs faster on my computer than the looped version).  I added a follow-up to the question because I am still not sure I fully understand when I can expect this to happen, and when not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on a longstanding issue when creating some closures https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15276.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.